# Animation for the child object

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I have parent object with animation and child object for which I want to create animation. But when I select child, I see animation of the parent object. How can I create animation for child without changing parent's animation?

[image]

I've made a new animation clip, but now I can't play it

```
 public Animation gateInsideHeadAnimation;
 gateInsideHeadAnimation.Play("gateInsideHead");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new Animator Component to the child object then you can create a animation for the child object only